# Why can't Elixir find __DIR__?

Tags: elixir-mix, elixir

I'm trying to run `mix test` for [elixir-json](https://github.com/cblage/elixir-json). When I do, I get

```
** (CompileError) /Users/me/Projects/elixir/json/test/json_test.exs:1: function '__DIR__'/0 undefined
    /usr/local/Cellar/erlang-r16/R16B01/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.0.9/include/yeccpre.hrl:128: :elixir_parser.yecctoken_end_location/1
    /usr/local/Cellar/erlang-r16/R16B01/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.0.9/include/yeccpre.hrl:113: :elixir_parser.yeccpars1/7
    /usr/local/Cellar/erlang-r16/R16B01/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.0.9/include/yeccpre.hrl:56: :elixir_parser.yeccpars0/5
    src/elixir_translator.erl:17: :elixir_translator.forms/4
    src/elixir_translator.erl:27: :elixir_translator.forms!/4
    src/elixir_compiler.erl:25: :elixir_compiler.string/2
    /private/tmp/elixir-pvTm/elixir-0.8.2/lib/elixir/lib/code.ex:229: Code.require_file/2
    /private/tmp/elixir-pvTm/elixir-0.8.2/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/parallel_require.ex:48: Kernel.ParallelRequire."-spawn_requires/5-fun-0-"/5
```

I installed Elixir via `brew` according to the [instructions](http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/1.html).

What's going wrong?

Comment: The solution is to use Elixir 0.9 (compiled from source), not 0.8, which is what's available via `brew`.

Comment: At the moment, `brew` comes with `elixir 0.9.3`. 
Try 
`brew update`

Comment: @RiccardoMarotti 0.10.0 even! http://elixir-lang.org/blog/2013/07/13/elixir-v0-10-0-released/

Comment: Both Elixir and elixir-json have advanced since the time this questions was answered. This particular issue is almost guaranteed to be resolved by now.

Answer (score 1):

The elixir version you have installed doesn't have the `__DIR__` macro.

I suggest you install elixir using `asdf`, it's a really great Elixir version tool, and you can install any version of the language you'd like.

https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf

asdf plugin-add elixir https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir.git